# What is the purpose of docker_registry_image in terraform docker provider?

Tags: mysql, windows, docker, terraform

I am learning how to work efficiently with docker images using terraform, in particular I would like to reduce the time used to download mysql images from registry

I know that docker_image resources have a [`keep_locally`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/r/image.html) argument, which I understand would download a new image only if it is not found in the docker local storage of the machine, but I would also like to download a new image in case there is a more updated one

I found out that there is a [`docker_registry_image`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/d/registry_image.html) and I understood that `pull_triggers` would allow terraform to realize when there is a new update and download it just then

```
provider "docker" {
  host = "npipe:////.//pipe//docker_engine"
}

data "docker_registry_image" "mysql" {
  name = "mysql:8"
}

resource "docker_image" "mysql" {
  name         = data.docker_registry_image.mysql.name
  pull_triggers = [data.docker_registry_image.mysql.sha256_digest]
  keep_locally = true
}

resource "docker_container" "mysql" {
  name    = "mysql"
  image   = docker_image.mysql.latest
        restart = "always"
  env     = [
    "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"
  ]
  volumes {
    volume_name    = "mysql-vol"
    container_path = "/var/lib/mysql"
  }
  ports {
    internal = 3306
    external = 3306
  }
}

provider "mysql" {
  endpoint = "127.0.0.1:3306"
  username = "root"
  password = "root"
}

resource "mysql_database" "test" {
  name = "test"
}
```

Here is my code and I would just like to know if it does what I think it does, which is to download a new image only if a new one is in the registry, and use the local one in case there is not

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `docker_registry_image` will provide metadata for the `mysql:8` image. It will have the following form:

```
{
  "id" = "sha256:f1f10a8a6014bda907889c2f649d7b832398432b6eb4849331818f01533db293"
  "name" = "mysql:8"
  "sha256_digest" = "sha256:f1f10a8a6014bda907889c2f649d7b832398432b6eb4849331818f01533db293"
}
```

The digest will match latest version of what is on docker hub [here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/mysql/library/mysql/latest/images/sha256-f1f10a8a6014bda907889c2f649d7b832398432b6eb4849331818f01533db293?context=explore):

[image]

Then `docker_image` will compare what it downloaded before with what is on the docker hub. If there is new version on docker hub, based on the  `sha256_digest`, new image should be pulled.

Comment: Great, so docker registry image would help to avoid unnecessary downloads, but for it to work properly I understand that it would need to be allowed to keep local images, so `keep_locally = true` is also needed, isn't it?

Also it would be great to be sure about: if only `keep_locally = true` but `docker_registry_image` is not used, terraform would download the an image the first time `terraform apply` is called and then not update it again?